# Need a table structure in html of table within table

Tags: html, angularjs

[image: Need Table like this.]

Please refer the table structure needed in the pic above. Can any body guide how this can be achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```css
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.tg td {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}
.tg th {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}
.tg .tg-7uzy {
  background: #cfc;
}
.tg .tg-yw4l {
  background: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-yw4l"></th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Col 1</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Col 2</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Col 3</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Col 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7uzy" rowspan="3">Row 1</td>
    <td class="tg-7uzy" rowspan="3"></td>
    <td class="tg-7uzy" rowspan="3"></td>
    <td class="tg-7uzy"></td>
    <td class="tg-7uzy"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7uzy"></td>
    <td class="tg-7uzy"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="3">Row 2</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="3"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="3"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7uzy"></td>
    <td class="tg-7uzy"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7uzy">Row 3</td>
    <td class="tg-7uzy"></td>
    <td class="tg-7uzy"></td>
    <td class="tg-7uzy"></td>
    <td class="tg-7uzy"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Row 4</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```